# Automatic favicon on sub-directories and files

Tags: html, favicon

My friend recently provided me with some disk space on his VPS and gave me the use of `http://IP/czdavid/`. I am not currently in need of a domain name since it will serve me as a file sharing site.

Now, the problem is that he has his favicon on the root of the IP and browsers search for it there. I can resolve the problem on individual pages with `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>`, the problem is that directory listing and actual files - images and text files and other opened in a browser - will show the domain favicon.

Is there any way to set a favicon for the entire sub-directory, short of getting a domain name?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

`favicon.ico` will be retrieved from the root of the site, unless specified in a `link` element on an HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of, would be to use the URL rewriting capabilities of the web server. At least in case of an apache, it would be possible to create a ruleset, that would deliver a different favicon depending on the referrer from the request.

But it is an ugly hack and only works, if browsers actually submit a referrer with a request for a favicon.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my server, so I can't test that.